# Is it possible to identify file name passing url in magento?

Tags: magento

How to identify coding having this file at magento .

For example,

[Link](http://localhost/index.php/about-magento-demo-store/) Mean

how to identify which file its denotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://localhost/index.php/about-magento-demo-store/` **is not** a file, it's CMS page content which is actually a row stored in the `cms_page` table in your database that gets filtered through a template to produce html page content that is pushed to your browser.

Look under the `CMS=>Pages` menu, you'll find a grid and if you search in the `url key` column for `about-magento-demo-store`, you can find the page content there.

Magento's content does not exist as static pages, it is data stored in the database that gets selected, filtered through templates and assembled into HTML that gets final styling from CSS. It only becomes a page, once it is downloaded by the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

1)Url redirects
look at the core_url_rewrite table and find the url that you requested.

if you find it, and target path starts like catalog/category/view/id/5,

that means catalog module, category controller, view action which you can find in

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php the method is viewAction.

2)Cms Pages
it can be a cms page

3)One of modules controller

It is the best way to install a profiler and see which controller handles your request.